# How to append values in an array of unknown size in C++?

Tags: c++, append

Just as I do in Python,

```
arr = []
data = input()
arr.append(data)
```

I know how to append data in C++ with for loop. But how to initialize an array of unknown size? It's size will depend on number of data points appended in loop section.

Comment: Are you limited to an array? Or can you use `std::vector`?

Answer (score 0):

Your code actually uses a Python [`list`](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/datastructures.html), not a Python [`array`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/array.html).

In C++, the closest match to your code would use an `std::vector`:

```
// In a header:
#include <string>
#include <vector>

// In your code
auto arr = std::vector<std::string>();
std::string data = "Hello world!";
arr.push_back( data );
```